# ** operator not supported in IE11. How to replace it with Math.pow using code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this example formula:

```
((97000 * ((5.50/100)/12)) / (1 - ((1 + ((5.50/100)/12))**(-1 * 120))))
```

The problem is that this code is not working correctly in IE11. I have tried this method to replace each `**` with `Math.pow`, but I cannot get it to work correctly:

```js
function detectAndFixTrivialPow(expressionString) {
  var pattern = /(\w+)\*\*(\w+)/i;
  var fixed = expressionString.replace(pattern, 'Math.pow($1,$2)');
  return fixed;
}

var expr = "((97000 * ((5.50/100)/12)) / (1 - ((1 + ((5.50/100)/12))**(-1 * 120))))";
var expr2 = detectAndFixTrivialPow(expr);

console.log(expr);
console.log(expr2); // no change...
```

Comment: Check the console in IE11 dev tools to find the error you can debug

Comment: Your simplistic regex will not deal correctly with the grouping parenthesis. (In fact, no regular expression can). Use a transpiler to convert modern JS code to run in old engines.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation - ie 11 doesn't support `**`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `^` is xor.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no working, calculate no same

Comment: @JaromandaX that code no working in IE, trying to fix that problem

Comment: @DanielA.White that problem.. do u have a solution?

Comment: just write it correct the first time.

Comment: @DanielA.White of course it is. Apologies

Comment: You won't find an easy regex - I'm sure someone would be able to come up with something, but, seriously, if you MUST support IE, then forget ES6 completely - IE11 only supports 11% of ES6 - seriously, it only supports 99% of ES5! and 1% of ES2016+ - stick to ES5 if you must support IE11 - or cut IE11, so that Internet Explorer is closer to dying from a thousand cuts

Comment: also @NisaAhmad a tool like babel might be able to help.

Comment: @DanielA.White - babel doesn't seem to care about `**`

Comment: @JaromandaX theres a plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator

Comment: well, I learned something - thanks @DanielA.White - oh, and it does well! *removes nail from internet explorers coffin*

Answer (score 0):

Trying this with a regular expression is going to be tough. Instead use a transpiler or at least an ECMAScript parser.

Here is an example how it can be done with the esprima parser. This API produces an AST tree. The code below looks for the `**` operator in that tree and collects the offsets where the input string should change. Then these offsets are sorted in descending order to apply them in the right order to the input string.

Note that this code does not attempt to save any parentheses. Those in the input are retained, and an extra pair is added for each of the `Math.pow` calls.

```js
function convert(input) {
    let modifs = [];
    
    function recur(ast) {
        if (Object(ast) !== ast) return; // not an object
        if (ast.type === "BinaryExpression" && ast.operator == "**") {
            modifs.push(
                [ast.range[0], 0, "Math.pow("], 
                [input.indexOf("**", ast.left.range[1]), 2, ","],
                [ast.range[1], 0, ")"]
            );
        }
        Object.values(ast).forEach(recur);
    }
    recur(esprima.parse(expr, { range: true }));
    
    modifs.sort(([a], [b]) => b - a);
    
    let output = [...input];
    for (let params of modifs) output.splice(...params);
    return output.join("");
}

// Demo
let expr = "((97000 * ((5.50/100)/12)) / (1 - ((1 + ((5.50/100)/12))**(-1 * 120))))"

let result = convert(expr);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/esprima@4.0.1/dist/esprima.min.js"></script>
```